# Painting areas inside an illustration - Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fill

I am having problems in filling my illustration with colours. I usually do these things by creating separate shapes or so but now this is done more by separate paths and I am confused. The shape builder tool doesn't recognize the separate areas well enough.

Is there a way to for example use the path of the balloon coming from mouth in closing the area of the tip of the finger and in the same time use it in the balloon path? What is the most quick and efficient approach in these kind of illustrations?

I am sorry for the elementary nature of this question and for the possibility this has been asked already.

Thank you.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you use the live paint tool:

[image]

You click on it, choose the color and start clicking on the areas, which will be marked by a thick red line.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I also have tried live paint but it gives me this.http://i58.tinypic.com/1o1vl0.png

Comment: Did you try using the divide tool and turning it into small pieces?